# Creating bech32 address on bitcoin core automatically generate another address on lightning network

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network, address-generation, bech32-address

my lightning network backend is `bitcoind`. Interesting when I execute `getnewaddress label bech32` another bech32 address is automatically generated. I found it because at the lightning network console pops up a new line `[INF] RPCS: [newaddress] addr=xxxxx` and it is not the same as the address at `bitcoind`.

It doesn't happen if I created with another wallet type such as legacy wallet.

So my questions are
1. why another address? what is the purpose of this automative generation?
2. what is the link between these two addresses? does deposit at one affect another in a descrete way?

Comment: Which lightning client are you using? c-lightning?

Comment: nope, the lightning network. https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd

Comment: That’s lnd, not the lightning network.

Comment: so lighting network includes lnd, c-lightning etc?

Comment: LND, C-Lightning, are implementations that both follow the specifications of the lightning network, and so, for the most part can communicate and function together on the same lightning network. It would be possible to: 1. fork LND, change one line, and then claim there is a third implementation on the lightning network. 2. Run a separate lightning network that listens on different ports, that exists on another plane than the lightning network we have today.

Comment: @HamiltonWong `lnd` and `c-lightning` are both Lightning implementations. You can choose either. It's like you can use Firefox or Chrome to browse the WWW.